# Protocol buffers stored as Oracle BLOB : python retrieve fails

Tags: python, oracle, blob, protocol-buffers

I am trying to read a protocolbuffer message that has been stored previously as a BLOB in an Oracle DB .
I am using python + google protocol buffers for python to read the data:

oracle 11g
  python 2.6.7
  google protocol buffers 2.4.1

Parsing of the message is fine: it does not return any exception.
However size of the message read is always 0  ( displaying the row as text shows that it is not empty )

```
cursor.execute("select myblob from mytable")
mydata = Data_pb2.MyData()
for dataDB in cursor:
    mydata.ParseFromString(dataDB[0])
    print "size:" + str(mydata.ByteSize())
```

Any idea ?
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

It is not specified which module is used to access Oracle, so I assume it is cx_Oracle.

When a LOB is read from Oracle, OCI provides a LOB locator which is wrapped into an object by cx_Oracle. So in the example, dataDB[0] is not a string but a cx_Oracle.LOB object. Depending on how ParseFromString is coded, it may or may not be properly converted into a string.

So I would use dataDB[0].read() as a parameter to ParseFromString.

```
cursor.execute("select myblob from mytable")
for dataDB in cursor:
    lob = dataDB[0].read()
    print "size:", len(lob)
    mydata = Data_pb2.MyData()
    mydata.ParseFromString(lob)
```

Also, the ByteSize() method is normally used at serialization time to calculate the size of the serialized message. I'm not sure it can be used just after parsing the message. In protocol buffer API, ByteSize() is clearly associated to serialization. It is actually pointless to call it at parse time, since the size of the buffer is already known before parsing.

Comment: Actually I had already tried the LOB read method, but same result. The size was added only for debugging purpose as I could not get it working . With your code I confirm the size of the LOB is not null, but parsing it still fails :(